# Weird scanf behaviour

Tags: c, scanf

I was working on a C program and I found a weird behaviour with `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *a, i; 
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf("%u", &a[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For 10 input I sent `+` and the output was like:

```
1                                                                                                                                                                                                             
0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
239646720                                                                                                                                                                                                     
32767                                                                                                                                                                                                         
0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
0                                                                                                                                                                                                             
239646727                                                                                                                                                                                                     
32767                                                                                                                                                                                                         
239646771                                                                                                                                                                                                     
32767
```

I expected a memory leak, could any one please explain me this behaviour ?

Comment: You have a pointer `a`, but *where does it point?*

Comment: Pointer fail UB :(

Comment: *I get strange behavior when I write to an array I have not allocated and then try to read it back. What's wrong?* A pointer to `int` is not an array, and you can't use it as one.

Comment: @KenWhite o.O??

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe inb4 '..but pointers and arrays are the same - website ccrap.gunge.com says so!'.

Comment: Please provide a reference to the standard defining "memory leak" and one requiring the code to generate one.

Comment: A "resource leak" (the general case of a memory leak) is if you allocate a "resource" and fail to deallocate it. Nowhere in your code do you allocate anything.

Comment: Undefined Behavior because `a` is pointing to some memory which is not allocated to you. Use `malloc` or `calloc` or simply declare an array `int a[10]`. Moreover, what you encountered is not a memory leak but a segmentation fault. I suggest you to first get a strong hold on pointers, array, memory allocation and also read about runtime errors.

Comment: DV for not enabling compiler warnings.  `int *a; ... scanf("%u",&a[i]) ;`  Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply wanted to store 10 integers to an array and later printing them, this would do:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[9],i ; 
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    for(i = 0;i<10;i++)`
    {
      scanf("%u",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0;i<10;i++) 
    {
      printf("%d\n",a[i]) ; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: " store 10 integers to an array" + `int a[9]` should be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not allocating any memory dynamically, you will not get a memory leak. You are, however, accessing unallocated memory, which is not the same as a memory leak.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by entering a +, but the behavior of using an uninitialized pointer is undefined.

Comment: But what i cant see here why sending + didnt change any thing?

Comment: You are using scanf in the wrong way. I don't really see the point in why something happens. scanf("%u") is used to read an unsigned integer, and you are sending something that is not.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems in your code:

- `a` is an uninitialized pointer, you should instead define it as an array of 10 `int`. As coded, your program has undefined behavior, it is quite surprising that it runs at all.
- you should check the return value of `scanf()`: if the conversion fails, it returns `0` or `EOF` and the destination is not modified, printing it has undefined behavior. Typing just a `+` sign for an integer results in a conversion failure.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[10], i; 
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (scanf("%u", &a[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "input error\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program i was dealing with was a vulnerable service l remarked this behaviour so i asked about it

Comment: Quite frail and vulnerable indeed